# For React / Redux apps, should we always clear the app state of that component when we route to a different component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

For a simple RESTful type of app, say, if it is blog posts, then when we see the list of all posts, and navigate to see just one post, should we actually set the app state's `posts` to `[]` or `null`?

And when we navigator from one post back to seeing all posts, should we set the app state's `post` to `null` as well?

(We do that probably in the `componentWillUnmount()` function:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.clearPost();
  }
```

where the `clearPost()` is an action creator for action type `CLEAR_POST`, and the reducer will return `null` when it sees this action type.)

Why? Because when the user sees a list of all posts, and now click on one post, we will see one post. But what if the network is down or slow? Then we will see the previously loaded post which could be a different post or even a deleted post.  If the network is down, we see this wrong record and it will stay there. If the network is slow or unstable, we see this wrong record and after N seconds, we will see the correct record.

The same with the full list of posts. When we navigate from other components (such as the show one post component) back to this index page, if the network is down or slow, we will also see the wrong content of the list of posts.  And then if network is down, this wrong list will stay. If network is slow, then the wrong list will be corrected after N seconds.

And what if customer service representatives are using this app? They might say to the customer, "NO, I see this record (or list), and it says such-and-such. According to the record, you are [...].  Computers do not lie, sir".

So is it always recommended to set the app state for that component back to empty array or `null` always, in the `componentWillUnmount()` function? Essentially, if we do have a constant called `INITIAL_STATE` for this component, we set it back to `INITIAL_STATE`?

Comment: I do not agree with this. Because a state slice can be used by more than one component. I think it's a good thing to clean the state in specific situations, for example, when you finish some complex processing flow, or something like that.